# QGIS freezes up when trying to save an edited attribute table

Tags: qgis

I'm using a shapefile from Statistics Canada, [available here](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lfsa000b21a_e.zip). This file maps Forward Sortation Areas (FSAs), which are the leading three characters of a Canadian postal code. When I try to add a new field, I cannot truly save it, as QGIS freezes up on me. When I open the file again, while most entries were saved, rows for territorial FSAs (CFSAUID starting with X or Y) are null. I've tried QGIS versions starting with QGIS 2 and I am up to 3.22.4 LTR Białowieża, with the same behaviour.

My minimum working example has been to create a new field with the field calculator to return a 1 for LANDAREA>5000 and 0 otherwise. Then, I try saving the attribute table with the freeze up and incomplete results as described above.

Is the operation invalid somehow, is there an issue with the shape file, or something else? I'm at a loss now.

Comment: Please add your function so it can be just copy-pasted. Some of us are lazy.

Comment: Why are you still working with QGIS 2 in 2022? Do have an old machine? So maybe that is the problem - file too large, not enough memory to proceed?

Comment: I'm working with QGIS 3 but I tested on QGIS 2 ...

Comment: user30184: I can equally reproduce this by setting whole field to 1, the specific function used isn't the key part.

Comment: I would recommend to try exporting the layer as a GeoPackage table and work with that instead. Shapefiles are outdated and have many limitations.

Comment: I can partly reproduce the issue. A new attribute is created and populated in a second or so but saving the edits of the shapefile makes QGIS unresponsive and the CPU usage jumps into 50% or more for all of the cores for a few minutes. However, QGIS does save the shapefile for me and all the new values seem to be in place. The shapefile is not big at all, only 1643 features and the size of the shp part is just 280 kB.

Comment: geodatabase to gepackage would work https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lfsa000b21f_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2092824&loc=//www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lfsa000b21f_e.zip

Comment: I had problems with something similar in the past because I had a software called docker running in the background, and it was not even visible in task manager at the time. Maybe it is a similar issue for you?

Comment: Ian Moffit: I tried this on multiple devices, and was having this freeze up on all of them. Some of them would have had Docker, others no.

Comment: This is a side effect of working with the "_cartographic_" dataset, as every tiny island is represented by a polygon **part**. That is, about 90% of the polygons are fairly simple single parts, and a few of them are extremely complex with thousands of parts for some of them, like in the great North.

Comment: If you don't mind having the FSA boundaries covering the water, you can use the "_digital_" [dataset](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lfsa000a21a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2021217&loc=//www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2021/geo/sip-pis/boundary-limites/files-fichiers/lfsa000a21a_e.zip) which is much smaller and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Is the attribute table very large? I am guessing so as your file is 269 MB, which is starting to get pretty big for a shapefile. My computer fan kicked on when I opened it and I have a very capable machine.

In all likelihood your computer does not have enough RAM to allow QGIS to store that much data at once, so it basically crashes when you try to make edits to it and it has to read it all into memory. One thing you should try is to press save and then leave your computer for a while - sometimes QGIS can manage the task but not while multiple things are going on. It may help to close all other programs if you can.

Otherwise, you're going to have to start looking into workarounds and other potential methods (python, block-reading), but we can come back to this if the above doesn't work.